# php socket server & client в одном флаконе

Tags: php, сокет

есть такая задача, на PHP написать socket сервер, который будет получать какие-то запросы, и передавать их другому серверу, по уже установленному socket соединению.
По отдельности обе задачи решаются без проблем, проблема в том что и как сервер и как клиент php запускает бесконечный цикл, и соответственно, если запустить сначала клиент, то до сервера дело не дойдет. Возможно есть какой-то способ, запустить клиент в фоне, и иметь к нему доступ?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь только один выход - писать по отдельности и использовать шину данных. Например redis pub/sub, или написать костыль на mysql.
Ну естественно в cli режиме все запускать.
Для упрощения кода используй ReactPHP, а также опиши условия и сигналы выхода из приложения или его перезапуска. Для этого очень полезен например `Symfony\Cache` компонент.
Во всяком случае это два разных процесса и работать должны они асинхронно

Comment: Ситуация усугубляется тем, что мне между клиентом и сервером нужно оперировать объектами, а за наводку спасибо!

Comment: В данном случае тебе надо подредактировать архитектуру. А объекты поддаются сериализации

Comment: В принципе любое общение сервисов (а у тебя должно быть минимум два демона-сервиса) между собой - строковое